# Something quite tricky in a python exercise

Tags: python, import, module

I wrote a python script `test1.py` in which I import a module called `test2`, then in `test2`, I did `import test1`; when I run `test1`, it works correctly; to my very big suprise, when I try to run `test2`, it outputs exactlly the same result as I run `test1`, despite these two files have very very different contents. but when I remove `import test2`, they work differently. So why this happened?

```
 import test2
 class test1():
 # do this
```

Well, `test1` works nicely up to here!

```
 import test1
 class test2():
 # do some other sharply different stuff
```

`test2` does work exactly the same as what `test1` does!
BUT, when `import test1` is removed from `class2`, `class2` will work fine. WHY??? thanks!!!

Answer (score 2):

[This is why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3082015/python-module-initialization-order/3082097#3082097).