# Import error in python

Tags: python, import, python-import

In file1.py:

```
      def test1():
        print "hi"
```

In file2.py:

```
      from file1 import test1

      def test2():
        print "hello"

      test1()
      test2()
```

Output:

```
      hi
      hello
```

Now in file 1 if i include test2 i get the following error:

```
    from file2 import test2

    def test1():
      print "hi"

   Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "file1.py", line 1, in ?
   from file2 import test2
   File "/root/pyt/file2.py", line 1, in ?
   from file1 import test1
   File "/root/pyt/file1.py", line 1, in ?
   from file2 import test2
  ImportError: cannot import name test2
```

Can some explain why and how to make it work?

Comment: Please preview your question before submitting it. It was quite unreadable.

Comment: cyclic import, read all about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name [doesn't exist in the module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3082015/python-module-initialization-order/3082097#3082097) by the time you try to access it.

Comment: I don't think so. The error is not an `AttributeError`. It's an `ImportError`. The module couldn't be imported because of the cyclic dependency.

Comment: @Noufal: It's only an `ImportError` because the attribute is being specified in an `import` operation. Any non-existent name will give this.

Comment: Vazquez-Abram:If we pass parameters to functions and check whether to import or not,then will it work

Comment: @Rajeev: It will work if the attribute you're accessing exists at that time.

Answer (score 4):

This is a circular import problem. You are importing `file2` from `file1` and then at the top level of `file2`, importing `file1` again. This means that `1` cannot load unless you import `2` and `2` cannot load unless you import `1.

As for how to make it work, can you explain what you want to do? Why don't you just put both these functions in the same module and import that in a single go?

Comment: No, not this either. Circular imports are valid in Python. What isn't valid is accessing attributes that don't exist.